# Differentiate between keyup on mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, keyup

I am currently using jquery with keyup. So when i alert `e.which` I get the keycode. My problem is that on computer keyboards I can detect the shift key, for example differentiating between  "`<`" and "`,`" or "`>`" and "`.`" 
On smartphone keyboards though, when i alert those two keys, they give me the same value, 190 and 88 respectively. How can i detect when i am pressing "`<`" and not "`,`" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know what character is being typed, look at `e.charCode`, not `e.which`.

Comment: cool. what yuo forgot to mention is that it will only work on keypress, not keydown or keyup